# Getting Total number of records in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get total number of records when the following query is run:

```
var cmd =new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Issue where BookID = @bid and IssueDate = @idate order by IssueDate desc", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bid", bookid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idate", DateTime.Now);
int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There is a record available in the database, but `val` always return -1.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is generally for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements, just FYI.

Comment: tip: `select count(*)` is going to be more efficient than forcing the db to prepare as if you were going to fetch all of those `select *` rows, then simply throw them away in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem :** You are trying to execute the query which returns the actual records from the table but not the Records count.

**Solution :** To get the Total Records from the Table, you need to call the Query as below:

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TABLENAME];
```

**Note :** To Read the records count you can either call `ExecuteReader()` or `ExecuteScalar()` methods.

but i would strongly recommned to call `ExceuteScalar()` when there is only one record/value to read.

**EDIT:** You don't need order by clause here as order of records will not effect the count value.

Try This:

```
var cmd =new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Issue where BookID = @bid and 
                                               IssueDate = @idate");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bid", bookid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idate", DateTime.Now);
int totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Column "Issue.IssueDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MohsinMustufa You really don't need the ORDER BY clause in your query, but it's true if you have an aggregate function in your projection you need to GROUP BY other columns used in your projection.

Answer (score 0):

You can either iterate through all records or make another query to count them yourself.

Also, don't forget to wrap your `SqlCommand` to a `using` statement because it implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

So you should use the already proposed COUNT based solutions.